# Python 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, numpy

Есть вот такой вот скрипт, для разделения массива на кластеры.

```
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
list_coord = [[-2, -6, 281], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [12, 11, 11],
              [1, 2, 2], [7, 6, 6], [13, 12, 12],
              [11, 13, 13], [6, 6, 6], [6, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8]]
list_coord_a=np.array(list_coord)
map_a=list_coord_a[:,:2]
min_value=np.min(map_a, axis=0) #коррекция для отрицательных координат
map_a=map_a-min_value
image=np.zeros(np.max(map_a, axis=0)+1, dtype=np.int32)
image[map_a[:,0], map_a[:,1]]=1
label, n=ndimage.label(image, structure=np.ones((3,3)))
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(f'Компонент {i}: \n {np.argwhere(label==i)+min_value}')
```

Изменил тип элементов массива с int на float и получаю вот такую ошибку

```
image = np.zeros(np.max(map_a, axis=0) + 1 , dtype=np.float64)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Не могу понять как её исправить, может кто подсказать?

Comment: С этим кодом получается другая ошибка `IndexError: index 15 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 15`, верните `+1`, который вы там потеряли. А та ошибка которую вы пишете не воспроизводится.

Comment: Похоже вы не только это изменение в коде сделали, покажите полный текст ошибки, если вы на ней настаиваете (полный трейсинг с указанием строк где ошибка) и полный изменённый код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код у меня успешно работает без всяких ошибок. Но я всё-таки смог добиться такой же ошибки как у вас и в той же строке. Ошибка там возникает только если сделать `map_a` массивом с числами c плавающей точкой:

```
list_coord_a=np.array(list_coord, dtype=np.float64)
map_a=list_coord_a[:,:2]
...
---> 10 image = np.zeros(np.max(map_a, axis=0)+1, dtype=np.int32)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Дело в том, что первый параметр у `np.zeros` - это `shape`, т.е. размеры создаваемой матрицы с нулями. Как вы себе представляете матрицу с дробным размером? Вот и `numpy` её не представляет. Ну, он бы мог, наверное, округлить, но не знает куда - вверх или вниз. А у самого `np.zeros` вы, конечно, можете ставить любой `dtype`, это не приводит ни к какой ошибке - нули могут быть любого типа, хоть комплексного, это не проблема вообще.

Comment: Да, я же и писал что с флоат проблема возникает, уже придумал как решить, спасибо за ответ!
h = 0.1
arr = (arr + 1) / h
arr = np.int64(arr)
print(arr)

Comment: @Leonid Ну, теперь то понятно, про что вы написали, но в коде вы поменяли на `np.float64` в другой строке `dtype`, в той, на которой ошибка выскакивает )